# How to configure Ansible in Jenkins Global Tool Configuration?

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible

I am running Jenkins on Docker container. I have installed ansible on my computer and Ansible plugin on Jenkins as well. `which ansible` is /usr/local/bin/ansible. How can I configure my system's Ansible on Jenkins Global Tool Configuration (http://localhost:8080/configureTools/) as the /usr/local/bin/ansible is not being recognized by Jenkins. 
"/usr/local/bin/ansible is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some agents)" is the error I get when I try to put the ansible path

Answer (score 0):

ansible should be installed on the server where you want to execute the ansible via Jenkins commands. `(but perhaps it exists on some agents)` -- this line means that in case there are slave registered to jenkins with ansible installed you can use them --> this error is generic. Also you can't use your local machine's ansible. Ansible tower is one such tool you can use but that requires custom installation on linux server

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but related to this, i`m in the same linux server with ansible already installed, and I have the exact same message when setting ansible plugin`s path. 
¿s this wrong?, or why I can`t use the local machine´s ansible as you mentioned error404 ?.. jic my playbook runs fine but now i need to integrate it through jenkins.